# How to cache queries at a time interval and send them all together when the time expired?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, caching

I am sure there are lots of tutorial for this kind of topic, but I can't find what I want because I don't know the jargon for it. So I ask StackOverflow.

Here the example:
People can Like or Dislike videos on Youtube, and the database should update the counts for Like or Dislike. However, it's impractical, especially for sites like Youtube, to update the database every time a user clicked on Like / Dislike button.

How can we cache the query / count numbers at a time interval, and when the time expired we send all the queries / update the database at one time? Or any similar technique for this kind of situation?

Comment: How is it impractical to update the database? That's what databases are for. - Alternatively you could link the like/disklike button to a GET or POST request and scan the server log files at regular time intervals. But I doubt that this would be more efficient in terms of runtime or programming effort.

Comment: I was just thinking that we could cache 300 or more likes / dislikes before updating a record. Because that seems like what reddit and other sites are doing.

Comment: You will be creating more problems than solving. Just try the simple database approach and add some hardware if it is lacking performance. Also, other sites might cache their website pages and re-build them at regular intervals, but not necessarily the related database entries.

Comment: Just be sure to use a database schema that allows row-level locking (such as innoDB) for write-intensive operations like this.

Answer (score 0):

So what you're observing is the time delay between something happening and being able to view the results of what happened.

And you're on the right path to only update periodically.

But you're on the wrong path as far as where to do the periodic updates.

Thing is you **WANT** to update the "database" every time ASAP (namely the database(s) responsible for *writing* - choose your missing corner of the [CAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) triangle) to capture everything pretty quickly, but for your visitors/viewers, you give them a slightly-behind (a few seconds to maybe a day, depending the situation) view of the write database(s).

You do NOT want to store this on the browser and potentially lose what the user did should the request fail, the internet go down, etc.

Slightly off topic - you typically do not try to "prematurely optimize" without data on knowing how much you're going to save by caching, buffering, etc.  Optimizations like that add complexity - and you will stay sane, longer, if you keep things simple for as long as possible.  Keep your design simple and optimize your bottlenecks once you know what they are.

Slightly more off topic - I'd recommend reading on distributed computing, specifically as it pertains to databases and then some design.  You'll realize these highly focused abstract problems all have "solutions" with various advantages and disadvantages.